# Scipy interpolation of non-uniform data

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a set of data loaded in from a csv file, with 1D arrays representing the x,y,z coords of the data points, and another 1D array, T, representing the value of a field at the corresponding points. The points are not uniform in space.

I am struggling to interpolate T a given point xi,yi,zi. scipy's interpn seems to want to accept T only as a 3D array, which doesn't make sense to me as T is simply 1D data?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit:

Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.0,1.5,1.1,1.3,1.4])
y = np.array([1.1,1.3,1.2,1.4,1.45])
z = np.array([1.0,1.1,1.4,1.2,1.0])
T = np.array([5.0,5.1,5.4,4.6,4.9])

point = ([1.2,1.1,1.25])
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

out = interpn((x,y,z),T,point)
print(out)
```

Cheers

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: You are passing a `tuple` of points in 3 dimensions like `(x,y,z)` and the value `T` as a 1-D array. `T` must be a 3-D array with the shape `(5,5,3)`. Also, your x, y, z arrays must have data in ascending order for interpolation.